# How to check if a parameter changed in a ".d.ts" File

Tags: javascript, typescript, .d.ts

*I dont know if this question once was asked, because I cant find it anywhere. (maybe I'm blind)*
*If this question is a dup, please tell me as this might also fixes my problem.*

I want to change the return inside my jsDocs to match what really returns and not `array | object`.

Here an Example:

```js
// class.someFunc: (str: string, bool?: boolean) => array
class.someFunc('string', true);

// class.someFunc: (str: string, bool?: boolean) => object
class.someFunc('string', false);
```

---

I tried with different types of defaults, thought it might change.

Both in the .d.ts function and in the jsDocs above.

```js
/** @param [bool=true] */
static someFunc(str: string, bool: boolean=true): array;

/** @param [bool=false] */
static someFunc(str: string, bool: boolean=false): object;
```

But it still used the above definition from the .d.ts even when `bool` was `false`.

Comment: It's good to search for duplicates, but in some cases they can be very difficult to find; you shouldn't feel bad about it even if your question is closed as a duplicate. The wording in your title or in the question may be useful to other people searching for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're looking to define typescript overloads

```
// these are the overloads that can actually be used for typing
function someFunc(str: string, bool: true): object;
function someFunc(str: string, bool: false): any[];
// this one is the real implementation, note that its inputs and 
// outputs encompass all of the overloads' types
function someFunc(str: string, bool: boolean): object | any[] {
  if (bool) return [];
  return {};
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was searching.
But when I tested it, it still showed `object` even when the `bool` was `false`.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @DragonDuck well an array (`[]`) is an object, and so is an empty object (`{}`). You can use `Array.isArray(something)` to test whether an object reference is an array instance.

Comment: I've tested this on the TS playground and it works as expected. You'd need to post more code I think. If you don't know the type of `bool` at compile-time, then it will always be `object | array`, there's no getting around that. But I can't really guess at the issue w/o seeing your usage.

Comment: I found what i did wrong, I copied it wrong (with equals instead of colons). Everything works now. Thanks 